# How to change the anchor text that has an embedded image with jquery?

Tags: jquery

The title sums it up.

An example anchor:

```
<a href="/xxx/yyy/zzz/2977088462?idx=2.3" data-folderid="2977088462" title="ATLAS TEST Share" class=""><img style="border-style: none" alt="ATLAS TEST Share" title="Shared by me." src="/Content/icons/folder_user.png">&nbsp;ATLAS TEST Share</a>


            var navItem = $("#favorite-products [title='" + cachedFolderText + "']");
            navItem.attr("title", FolderDescription); // this works
            navItem.text('&nbsp;'+FolderDescription); // this changes the text but also remove the image from the object.
```

What I'm finding is that the image is wiped-out and replace with the text, is there something I'm missing to preserver the image and just change the text?

**Results based off of James Montagne code**

```
<a href="/Buyer/Favorite/FavSummary/2976199074?idx=2.2" data-folderid="2976199074" title="ABC Finally4" class="">
                            <img style="border-style: none" alt="Normal Folder" title="Not shared" src="/Content/icons/folder.png">ABC Finally 
                        ABC Finally4</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `contents` to get the contents including text nodes.  You can then replace just the text node.

Here's an example or replacing the first text node:

http://jsfiddle.net/8LMZn/1/

```
$("a").contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
}).eq(0).replaceWith("NEW TEXT");
```

**UPDATE**:  This will replace the first non-whitespace text node.

http://jsfiddle.net/8LMZn/4/

```
$("a").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length > 0;
}).eq(0).replaceWith("NEW TEXT");
```

Ideally though, you should wrap the text in a `span` or some other container to make it easier to access.

Comment: Thanks James. I just tested it with an image instead of a span and it works perfectly. One question that you might answer ( and save me from having to search for it ) is what is node type == 3 and the valid values for this property?  Regards, Stephen

Comment: 3 means text node, it's the only value I've ever used so I don't know the other values.

Comment: I just slaved in the code, and although it worked with the online sample, it is now replacing the text correctly but it should be after the image instead of before,  any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in the fiddle?  I don't see any reason why replacing the text would cause it to move before the image.  http://jsfiddle.net/8LMZn/2/

Comment: Yes, that's the weird thing. I just posted an example of the code running in my project.

Comment: Oh, you must have blank text before the image.  So it is replacing a text node that has just whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead:

```
navItem.html(navItem.html()+'&nbsp;'+FolderDescription);
```